# Walk through the directories using python?

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am new in Python. I have a folder called logs, naturally they will be categorized into folders, and within those folders there will also be sub-folders for sub categories. Now my problem is I have a function that walks through sub directories and get the logs folder .

My question is why below code is not working properly.I am getting logs folder files in else block also.

```
def printFiles(directory_path):    
    for root, _, filenames in os.walk(directory_path):
        dirname = os.path.basename(root).strip()
        if str(dirname) == 'logs' and len(dirname) == 4:
            for filename in filenames:
                file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                withLogFile(file_path)
        else:
            for filename in filenames:
                file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                withoutLogfile(file_path)
```

Comment: You have the exact same code in the else block. What did you want to happen if the directory name was not logs?

Comment: How did you know that the `print` comes from the `else` block once the inside code of `if` and `else` are the same?

Comment: Are you stuck on Python 2.6? Python 2.6 is a decade old now, and it hasn't gotten security updates since 2013. The whole 2.x line is about a year from end-of-life.

Comment: Actually i am creating separate files one is logfileDatils.txt and other is filesDatils.txt

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, your problem is that you want all files in any subdirectory of a folder called logs. Currently your code only decides something is a log file if it is directly in the folder 'logs'. To fix this, change

```
dirname = os.path.basename(root).strip()
if str(dirname) == 'logs' and len(dirname) == 4:
```

to

```
if 'logs' in root.split('/'):
```

Your current code checks if the last part of the current directory is called 'logs' (and is of length 4, which I think is redundant). The new code checks if the folder logs is anywhere in the file path for the directory you are looking in. The split on '/' is to make sure you don't hit something like /blogs accidently.

Comment: @Ban Glad I could help!